# Use vscode as editor for sops

Tags: visual-studio-code, mozilla-sops

I can't seem to get `sops` to work with `Visual Studio Code` as its editor. `vscode` is already in the `PATH`. However, `sops` prints the decrypted content on the console instead of opening the editor.

```
c:\>code .
----^ this opens the Visual Studio Code editor

c:\>echo %EDITOR%
"code"

c:\>sops-3.1.0.exe --decrypt encrypted.txt
Decrypted content
```

I've tried setting `EDITOR` to `vscode`'s full path, same issue.

Has anyone used `vscode` with `sops` or know how to do this in Windows?

Comment: p.s: Could someone with enough credit please add ''mozilla-sops" tag? I couldn't.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Figured it out!

I should be using `code --wait` as my `EDITOR`

Ref: https://github.com/mozilla/sops/issues/127

Comment: For me I'd forgot to "export" EDITOR assignment, which means it was correct at my prompt, but is not exported to sops.
export EDITOR="code --wait"